# Problema al exportar datos a Excel usando PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Estoy con un asunto de phpexcel, el cual importo un Excel mediante PHPExcel, lo trato y organizo y posteriormente lo saco a otro Excel ya tratado, tengo todo lo demás, el problema lo tengo al intentar exportar el excel. Tengo la siguiente información:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'idAsignatura');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Nombre');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'CompetenciasEspecificas');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'Competencias Basicas');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'Competencias Generales');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', 'Competencias Transversales');

 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:F1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
 
$rowCount   =   2;
while($row  =   $my_array->fetch_all()){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, mb_strtoupper($row['idAsignatura'],'UTF-8'));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, mb_strtoupper($row['Nombre'],'UTF-8'));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, mb_strtoupper($row['Competencias Especificas'],'UTF-8'));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, mb_strtoupper($row['Competencias Basicas'],'UTF-8'));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount, mb_strtoupper($row['Competencias Generales'],'UTF-8'));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount, mb_strtoupper($row['Competencias Transversales'],'UTF-8'));
   
    $rowCount++;
}
$objWriter  =   new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
 
 
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="you-file-name.xlsx"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');  
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Cuando intento exportarlo me da el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing.php:144 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing.php on line 144
```

No consigo dar con la tecla ¿Podéis ayudarme?

Comment: No se sabe de dónde sale `$my_array`, pero el error dice que esa variable no tiene el array que esperas. Si es una consulta a BD, posiblemente contenga FALSE (porque falló) en vez del resultado esperado. ¿Por qué no añades una validación para programar de forma defensiva y poderle decir al usuario que no hay resultados a pintar en el PDF?